# How to bypass siteminder for url containing single quote?

Tags: jsp, authentication, web-applications, xss, siteminder

In my application code I am using this kind of url to redirect user from one page to another page: `http://myhost:8001/myapp/list.jsp?name=abc'd&age=10`
Here name is the dynamic field which user can edit on the first page which can contain single quote inside it.

Now the problem is when I use siteminder for authentication each and every url gets passed through it. And siteminder thinks of this single quote as an attempt for such attack and blocks this url and takes user to some access blocked page.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that URI encoding will work -- Siteminder is smart enough to figure that out.  Some other kind of encoding, like base64, or just replacing apostrophes with something else and then replacing it back on the server side.  Alternatively you can disable the BadCSSChar checking for the apostrophe in the Siteminder agent configuration.  Just beware that you may be opening your site up to XSS attacks and your application must be responsible for checking any user-supplied strings before displaying them on a Web page.

Answer (score 0):

Try URI encoding the single quote with %27.

Comment: This didn't help. Siteminder still restricts access to this url. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have code running at both ends, you can send mySingleQuoteToken and your code at the far end can detect that and replace it with a '

Pre-processing on sending side - before calling java.net.URLEncoder:

```
url_new = url_old.replaceAll("'", "mySingleQuoteToken");
```

Post-processing on receiving side - after calling java.net.URLDecoder:

```
url_new = url_old.replaceAll("mySingleQuoteToken", "'");
```

Comment: This answer is poor quality, do you have a code sample that can elaborate on your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Below steps should help you solve the problem.

1. Enclose the fields name and age inside a HTML form
2. Specify the URL without query parameters using action attribute.
3. Specify the method as POST using method attribute.
4. Specify the enctype as application/x-www-form-urlencoded using enctype attribute
5. Enter the values and submit the form.

   ```
   <form action="/myapp/list.jsp" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
       <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""/>
     <br/>
     <input type="text" id="age" name="age" value=""/>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit"/>
   </form>
   ```